# Consuming a custom event in F#

Tags: f#

Event handling in F# is really causing headache for me. The error I'm facing is

```
This expression was expected to have type
    obj -> unit    
but here has type
    System.EventHandler<obj>
```

I'm publish the event as follows

```
type ...
    let dataChanged = new Control.Event<obj>()

    [<CLIEvent>]
    member this.DataChanged = dataChanged.Publish

    member private this.NotifyDataChanged(sender : obj) =
        dataChanged.Trigger(sender)
```

And I'm trying to catch it like this

```
type ...

    let dataChangedHandler = new System.EventHandler<obj>(fun sender ->  this.DataItems_DataChanged(sender))

    do this.DataItems.DataChanged.Add(dataChangedHandler)

    member private this.DataItems_DataChanged(sender : obj) =
        ...
```

As said, the code doesn't compile. I've tried different variations but just can't get it working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The compiler clearly tells you: `dataChangedHandler` is expected to be of type `obj -> unit`. Just don't wrap it in `EventHandler`, it'll work.

Comment: @fyodor-soikin What would be the correct syntax in that case? As far as I understand, I can't just use `new obj(fun sender ->  this.DataItems_DataChanged(sender))`

Comment: `new obj` creates an instance of `obj`, but you need `obj -> unit`. It's just a function.

Comment: @fyodor-soikin Now I see what you mean! Would you be so kind and put it as an answer so I can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler clearly tells you: `dataChangedHandler` is expected to be of type `obj -> unit`, which is just a function.

Just don't wrap it in `EventHandler`, it'll work:

```
let dataChangedHandler = fun (sender: obj) -> this.DataItems_DataChanged(sender)
```